# How to create multiple thunderbird mail accounts?

Tags: 10.10, thunderbird

How to create multiple thunderbird mail accounts in ubuntu 10.10 ? I just want to show only one account in each thunderbird shortcuts.. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with **firefox**, you can create a new profile starting the application with

```
thunderbird -no-remote -ProfileManager
```

(the `-no-remote` option is required to start a new instance, if another is already running).

Once created one or more profiles, to start with a given profile you can create a launcher with the following command

```
thunderbird -no-remote -P <profile>
```

where <profile> is a profile name.

Answer (score 1):

To add multiple account go to Edit>Account Settings then use the button in bottom left corner.
You can change the account visualization using the left column.

Answer (score 1):

Just step by step,

1. You can see I have already had an account which is called zhuxu...3.com. I am sure about you already have one, what you need to do is to click your created account in your thunderbird.
2. Then you will see "Create a new account" (it so big that you can find it easily), click it and fills your another email account in Pop-up box.
3. The rest steps are familiar with the steps you create first email account.
4. Click "Continue" button,Choose "IMAP" or "POP3",the different result is that you not store or store mail on your computer. However When I choose "POP3",if It says that username or password is not correct (the second mail I added is QQ mail, and I choose "POP3",maybe it is for another reason,Then I choose "IMAP",it worked), you can choose another one.
5. The last thing you need to do is click "Create Account" button.Then the second account will appear in the upper left corner of Thunderbird.

Comment: If you need to post images, either leave the link so I can add it later, or drop by the [chat] so someone can add them for you. (I can't since I don't have thunderbird, and also I use Gnome3/Debian)