# How do I set up Thuderbird for multiple email accounts in Ubuntu

Tags: thunderbird

I have recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu (so am a novice !!!) and want to use Thunderbird for multiple email accounts. In windows, when I clicked the Thunderbird icon, Profile manager opened a window which allowed me to choose which profile (email account) I wanted to open. How do I set this up in Ubuntu. I have tried the suggestions on various websites, but I can't seem to get the "User profile Chooser" to display when I start Thunderbird as the strings given don't seem to work in the Ubuntu terminal. Thanks for any help.

Comment: While you can use a separate profile for each account, Thunderbird is intended to be used with multiple email accounts in a single profile. Multiple profiles are more intended for the case where multiple users use the same login and so it is useful to keep their emails separate. Add subsequent ones with `File->New->Existing Email Account` or `Edit->Account Settings`.

Comment: Not sure I understand the answer. I have separate profiles for my personal and business email accounts in Windows Thunderbird, and can choose which one I want to open for that session using Profile Manager. It's a far neater solution than having multiple email accounts open and showing at the same time. Profile Manager allows you to easily switch between profiles.

Comment: Please read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42421/how-to-create-multiple-thunderbird-mail-accounts *Do you need to set your Thunederbird icon to always open Profile-Manager?*

Comment: Fixed !!! I copied and pasted a command line (thunderbird -ProfileManager) from one of the websites into the terminal and it didn't work. On another website someone had the same problem, but replaced it with "thunderbird -profilemanager" and it worked, as it did for me, so obviously case sensitive. All OK now, and I can chose which profile I want to open !!

Comment: David, just to confirm when I click the Thunderbird icon now, I am always presented with a choice of which profile I want to open for that session (by unchecking the "Don't ask at start up" box). Thx